# Display Alternative color_bar value in Formattable Table

Tags: r, knitr, kableextra, formattable

Is it possible to populate a formattable color_bar with an alternative display value (i.e. a value other than the value used to determine the size of the color_bar)

In the table below I want to override the values with the following display values for ttl to:

c(1000,1230,1239,1222,1300,1323,1221)

```
library(tidyverse)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
library(formattable)

tchart <- data.frame(id = 1:7,
  Student = c("Billy", "Jane", "Lawrence", "Thomas", "Clyde", "Elizabeth", "Billy Jean"),
  grade3 = c(55,70,75,64,62,55,76),
  ttl = c(105,120,125,114,112,105,126),
  avg =c(52.31,53.0,54.2,51.9,52.0,52.7,53.0))

  tchart %>% 
  mutate(id = cell_spec(id, "html", background = "red", color = "white", align = "center")) %>%
  mutate(grade3 = color_bar("lightgreen")(grade3)) %>% 
  mutate(ttl = color_bar("lightgray")(ttl)) %>% 
  mutate(avg = color_tile("white","red")(avg)) %>% 
  kable("html", escape = F) %>%
  kable_styling("hover", full_width = F) %>% 
  column_spec(4, width = "4cm")
```

I checked the documentation and didn't see this as a possibility, but I was hoping there was a workaround or custom function solution.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can quite pass it another set of values, but there are a couple of options that you might find workable.

One thing to note first is that `color_bar()` can accept two values - a color, and a function that will take the vector of values and transform them to numbers between 0 and 1. By default, that function is `formattable::proportion()`, which compares everything against the max value. But if you used your display values for `ttl`, you could conceivably transform the bars to be whatever length you wanted by writing your own function. (See: https://rdrr.io/cran/formattable/man/color_bar.html)

Another possibility would be to make your own formatter. Some examples here:
https://www.littlemissdata.com/blog/prettytables

So, I think you can put the numbers you want in the display, and hopefully can use a function to transform or map those values to get the bar lengths between 0 and 1 that you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Add a new variable `ttl_bar` to determine the size of the bar, and let variable `ttl` display the value. I use `gsub()` to replace the `ttl_bar` to `ttl`.

```
tchart <- data.frame(id = 1:7,
                     Student = c("Billy", "Jane", "Lawrence", "Thomas", "Clyde", "Elizabeth", "Billy Jean"),
                     grade3 = c(55,70,75,64,62,55,76),
                     ttl = c(1000,1230,1239,1222,1300,1323,1221),
                     avg =c(52.31,53.0,54.2,51.9,52.0,52.7,53.0),
                     ttl_bar = c(105,120,125,114,112,105,126))

tchart %>% 
  mutate(id = cell_spec(id, "html", background = "red", color = "white", align = "center")) %>%
  mutate(grade3 = color_bar("lightgreen")(grade3)) %>% 
  mutate(avg = color_tile("white","red")(avg)) %>% 
  mutate(ttl = pmap(list(ttl_bar, ttl, color_bar("lightgray")(ttl_bar)), gsub)) %>% 
  select(-ttl_bar) %>% 
  kable("html", escape = F) %>%
  kable_styling("hover", full_width = F) %>% 
  column_spec(4, width = "4cm")
```

In a more careful way, rewrite `gsub()` as this `mutate(ttl = pmap(list(ttl_bar, ttl, color_bar("lightgray")(ttl_bar)), ~ gsub(paste0(">", ..1, "<"), paste0(">", ..2, "<"), ..3)))`.

I come up with a better way to use function in `color_bar()` as the following code.

```
override = function(x, y) y / 200

tchart <- data.frame(id = 1:7,
                     Student = c("Billy", "Jane", "Lawrence", "Thomas", "Clyde", "Elizabeth", "Billy Jean"),
                     grade3 = c(55,70,75,64,62,55,76),
                     ttl = c(105,120,125,114,112,105,126),
                     avg =c(52.31,53.0,54.2,51.9,52.0,52.7,53.0),
                     ttl_bar = c(1000,1230,1239,1222,1300,1323,1221))

tchart %>% 
  mutate(id = cell_spec(id, "html", background = "red", color = "white", align = "center")) %>%
  mutate(grade3 = color_bar("lightgreen")(grade3)) %>% 
  mutate(avg = color_tile("white","red")(avg)) %>% 
  mutate(ttl = color_bar("lightgray", fun = override, ttl)(ttl_bar)) %>% 
  select(-ttl_bar) %>% 
  kable("html", escape = F) %>%
  kable_styling("hover", full_width = F) %>% 
  column_spec(4, width = "4cm")
```